# Want to automate firebase login via firebase CLI and init for a pre defined gcp project. New to automation, is it possible to automate?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Need to automate compound index generation in firebase cli as below

```
curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash
firebase login ##looking a way to automate it
firebase init ##looking a way to automate it
```

replacing firestore.indexes.json to create index on user and timestamp field as below

```
{
  "indexes": [{ 
    "collectionGroup": "notifications",
    "queryScope": "COLLECTION",
    "fields": [
      { "fieldPath": "users", "order": "DESCENDING" },
      { "fieldPath": "timestamp", "order": "DESCENDING" }
    ]
  }
],
  "fieldOverrides": []
}
```

and run

```
firebase deploy --only firestore:indexes
```

**to automate firestore functionalities and compound index creation.** **Is it feasible..?**

Comment: Not sure I understood what the issue you are facing is, you basically want to create an automated new project setup, what do you intend to use to automate? also, what do you mean with `##stuck with authentication`? Is that part of the question?

Comment: Actually,  Intention is to avoid manual creation of compund index for the firestore database, instead plan is to achieve it as part of ci/cd in gitlabs. Can Firebase login be achieved by any google cloud service account. So i want to automate firbase cli setup, login and init part.